# viewport properties how to use properly

Tags: ios, responsive-design, viewport, meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Due to the fact that `user-scalable=no` means we do not let the user zoom in or out of the page. Then why do we need to use `initial-scale=1.0` and `maximum-scale=1.0`? Is it necessary to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, `maximum-scale=1.0` is unneeded since the page can't be zoomed anyway. Setting `minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0` is a common pattern that's almost equivalent to `user-scalable=no`. Almost because some browsers will load the page at a scale such that all content width is visible (e.g. Chrome on Android does this) so the user may start off at a scale that's not 1.0 and can't zoom. However, adding `initial-scale=1.0` forces the zoom to 1.0.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This really helps me :)